# React - How to restrict Google Places API results to specific countries dynamically

Tags: reactjs, google-places-api

I am trying to restrict Autocomplete results to a country dynamically. Right now i am able to initialize the API script and get reslts for the default country, but once a user changes the country, i am running the following script which is just not doing anything:

```
setAutocompleteCountry = () => {
    if (this.state.country == 'all') {
      autoComplete.setComponentRestrictions({'country': []});
    } else {
      autoComplete.setComponentRestrictions({'country': country});
    }
}
```

I appreciate any insights and here is the relevant code in the component:

```
let autoComplete;
let country = 'vn'

class ServiceableAreas extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            query: '',
            country: 'th'
        }
        this.autoCompleteRef = React.createRef(null);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        const { city } = this.props.values;
        if (city !== prevProps.values.city) {
            if (city !== null) {

                if (city === 'Bangkok') {
                    country = 'th'
                }
                else if (city === 'Vientiane') {
                    country = 'la'
                }
                else if (city === 'Hoh Chi Min') {
                    country = 'vn'
                }
                this.setAutocompleteCountry()
            }
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadScript(
            "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD4FpFjf7nQ0LDaz3qi1EShX2p4Yy0rnxo&libraries=places",
            () => this.handleScriptLoad(this.setQuery, this.autoCompleteRef)
          );
    }

    setQuery = (query) => {
        this.setState({query})
    }
    
    // dynamically load JavaScript files in our html with callback when finished
    loadScript = (url, callback) => {
        let script = document.createElement("script"); // create script tag
        script.type = "text/javascript";
    
        // when script state is ready and loaded or complete we will call callback
        if (script.readyState) {
        script.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (script.readyState === "loaded" || script.readyState === "complete") {
            script.onreadystatechange = null;
            callback();
            }
        };
        } else {
            script.onload = () => callback();
        }
    
        script.src = url; // load by url
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script); // append to head
    };

    // handle when the script is loaded we will assign autoCompleteRef with google maps place autocomplete
    handleScriptLoad = (updateQuery, autoCompleteRef) => {
        // assign autoComplete with Google maps place one time
        autoComplete = new window.google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        autoCompleteRef.current,
        { types: ["(regions)"], componentRestrictions: { country: country } }
        );
        // autoComplete.setFields(["address_components", "formatted_address"]); // specify what properties we will get from API
        autoComplete.setFields(["address_components"]); // specify what properties we will get from API
        // add a listener to handle when the place is selected
        autoComplete.addListener("place_changed", () =>
            this.handlePlaceSelect(updateQuery)
        );
    }

    // Set the country restriction based on user input.
    setAutocompleteCountry = () => {
        if (this.state.country == 'all') {
          autoComplete.setComponentRestrictions({'country': []});
        } else {
          autoComplete.setComponentRestrictions({'country': country});
        }
    }

    handlePlaceSelect = async (updateQuery) => {
        const addressObject = await autoComplete.getPlace(); // get place from google api
        const query = addressObject.formatted_address;
        updateQuery(query);
        console.log(addressObject);
        const _area = addressObject.address_components.filter(item => item.types.filter(t => t === 'sublocality_level_1').length > 0)[0]
        //console.log('_AREA: ', _area)
        if (_area !== undefined) {
            const area = _area.long_name;
            console.log('AREA: ', area)
            if (this.props.values.serviceableAreas.indexOf(area) === -1) {
                const areas = [...this.props.values.serviceableAreas, area]
                this.props.setServiceableAreas(areas)
                this.setState({query: ''})
            }
            else {
                this.setState({query: ''})
                this.focus()
            }
        }
        else {
            this.setState({query: ''})
            this.focus()
        }
      }
 
    render() {
        const { values } = this.props;
  
              <div>
                <Grid container spacing={1}>
                    <Grid item md={12}>
                        <TextField
                            inputRef={this.autoCompleteRef}
                            label='Area'
                            placeholder="Enter area"
                            onChange={event => this.setQuery(event.target.value)}
                            value={this.state.query}
                            InputProps={{ disableUnderline: true }}
                            fullWidth
                        />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>        
            </div>
        )
    }
}
            
export default ServiceableAreas
```

Comment: *which is just not doing anything* - what do you expect should happen? How do you know it's not doing anything?

Comment: @MrUpsidown I mean it's not doing what I expected, that is, it's not changing the google autocomplete country restriction when I change the country

Comment: How do you test it? `autoComplete.setComponentRestrictions({'country':'th'});` *should* set the country restriction to Thailand.

Comment: Your feedback was much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic example that demonstrates the use of `setComponentRestrictions()`. Type a letter and you will see suggestions in France. Change the option to *USA* and click back in the autocomplete field and you will see suggestions from USA.

```js
function initialize() {

  var ac = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
      types: ['geocode'],
      componentRestrictions: {
        country: 'fr'
      }
    });

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('country'), 'change', function() {

    ac.setComponentRestrictions({
      'country': this.value
    });
  });
}
```

```css
#autocomplete {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text">
<select id="country">
  <option value="fr">France</option>
  <option value="us">USA</option>
</select>

<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initialize" async defer></script>
```